# Is it possible to find a real function $v(x, y)$ so that $x^3 + y^3 + i v(x, y)$ is holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Is it possible to find a real function $v(x, y)$ so that $x^3 + y^3 + i v(x, y)$ is holomorphic?

I'm not sure I understand the implications of this question so I had a tough time filtering through those already asked. If there already a good example answer to a similar question though, please feel free to send it my way!

Answer (score 2):

No. The real part of a holomorphic function is harmonic. $u(x,y) = x^3 + y^3$ is not harmonic.

Comment: What proof or defintion tells us that a non-harmonic real part of a function necessitates it being a non-holomorphic function?

Comment: The Cauchy-Riemann equations, along with the fact that a holomorphic function is at least $C^2$ (and in fact infinitely differentiable).

Comment: Aah! Yes! That makes sense! Thanks so much!!